# Как правильно вызывать функцию такого вида через setInterval?

Tags: javascript

```js
if(scrollToTopButton.addEventListener) {
 scrollToTopButton.addEventListener('click', topScroll);
} else {
 scrollToTopButton.attachEvent('onclick', topScroll);
}

function topScroll(event) {
 event = event || window.event;
 var topInterval = setInterval(topScrollUpSteps(event), 20);
 console.log(event.pageY);
 function topScrollUpSteps (event) {
  if (event.client >= 160) {
   event.pageY = event.pageY - 20;
   console.log(event);
  } else {
   clearInterval(topInterval);
  }
 }
}
```

Делаю скрипт плавной прокрутки до верха страницы. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что setInterval не работает по какой-то причине. Когда я не передаю в аргументе event то пишет, что event не найдет, а когда передаю то просто ничего не происходит. В чем проблема?

Comment: попробуйте анонимную стрелочную функцию передать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var topInterval = setInterval(
  function() { topScrollUpSteps(event); }, 20);
```

Если я правильно понимаю, что Вы хотите сделать, то Вам надо использовать не `event.pageY`, а `window.pageYOffset` и `window.scrollBy( , );`.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_pagexoffset.asp

Comment: не работает, просто ничего не происходит

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi Вызов правильный. Мне непонятно, чего Вы рассчитываете добиться манипуляциями с `event.pageY`.

Comment: скролла вверх, или таким образом не добиться? Просто даже console.log что внутри if не срабатывает при вызове таким образом